# Code is not properly searching text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

```
#
# Obtain user input for file name, and open it
#
inFile = open(input("Enter file name: "), "r")
#
# Process data and address possible errors
#
countDinner = 0
countLodging = 0
countConference = 0
valueDinner = 0
valueLodging = 0
valueConference = 0
done = False
while not done :
line = inFile.readline()
try :
    s = line
    serviceAmount = ';'.join(s.split(';')[1:-1]) #Removes date and name regardless of format
    serviceAmount.split(";")
    s.lower()
    if "dinner" in s :
        countDinner = countDinner + 1
        valueDinner = valueDinner + int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
        print("Dinners: ", countDinner, "Value of Dinner sales: ", valueDinner)
    elif "lodging" in s :
        countLodging = countLodging + 1
        valueLodging = valueLodging + int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
        print("Lodging: ", countLodging, "Value of Lodging sales: ", valueLodging)
    elif "conference" in s :
        countConference = countConference + 1
        valueConference = valueConference + int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
        print("Conferences: ", countConference, "Value of Conference sales: ", valueConference)
    elif line == "" :
        done = True
    else :
        print("Invalid file format.")
except FileNotFoundError :
    print("Unable to find file.")
finally :
    done = True
    inFile.close()
```

Returns "Invalid file format" even when the document is set up specifically for this code. I'm not getting a syntax error, so I'm not sure whats wrong.
The document contains the text:

```
John;Lodging;123;050617 
Tyler;Conference;123;081497 
Taylor;Dinner;453;041798
```

Comment: In the document, the lists of names to services are on separate lines, not sure why it won't show that here.

Comment: Use a context manager. Don't use a `while` loop, use a for-loop over the file handle. Holy guacamole, man, this is not how you should be working with files in Python. Also, you haven't explained what this code *is suppose to do*.

Comment: Im really new to programming, this is an assignment for the first class I've ever taken in it. I'm trying. Thank you for the input though.

Comment: But fundamentally, I'm pretty sure your problem is that your second column is always uppercase, and you are checking with lower-case strings, i.e. `if 'dinner' in s:`. On the previous line, you did `s.lower()`, but this *returns a **new string** which you must assign to a variable* or else it gets discarded.

Comment: python also has functions!

Comment: Additionally, this line `serviceAmount.split(";")` does nothing, since the list that is returned is immediately discarded because you don't assign it to anything. Head's up: `int(filter(str.isdigit, s))` is going to throw a `TypeError`

Comment: The assignment is as follows: A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client the service sold, the amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service category. Display an error if the file does not exist or the format is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things you aren't doing quite right here. I tried to not only fix the issue you posted about, but also write some code that should be more clear and easier to use. I left comments to explain things.

```
# Don't open the file here, just get the file name. We will open in later
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

# I think using dicts is more clearn and organized. Having so many variables I think makes the code messy
counts = {"Dinner": 0,
"Lodging": 0,
"Conference": 0}

values = {"Dinner": 0,
"Lodging": 0,
"Conference": 0}

# Lets try to open the file
try:
    with open(fname, 'r') as inFile: # Use "with", this way the file is closed automatically when we are done reading it
        for linenum, line in enumerate(inFile): # I want to enumerate each line. If there is an error on a line, we can display the line nmber this way
            line = line.lower().split(';')[1:-1] # lets make it all lower case, then split and drop as needed
            print(line)
            if "dinner" in line :
                counts["Dinner"] += 1 # x += 1 is the same as x = x + 1, but cleaner
                values["Dinner"] += int(line[1])
                print("Dinners: {} Value of Dinner sales: {}".format(counts["Dinner"], values["Dinner"]))
            elif "lodging" in line :
                counts["Lodging"] += 1
                values["Lodging"] += int(line[1])
                print("Lodging: {} Value of Dinner sales: {}".format(counts["Lodging"], values["Lodging"]))
            elif "conference" in line :
                counts["Conference"] += 1
                values["Conference"] += int(line[1])
                print("Conference: {} Value of Dinner sales: {}".format(counts["Conference"], values["Conference"]))
            else :
                print("Invalid file format on line {}".format(linenum)) # Here is why we used enumerate in the for loop
except FileNotFoundError: 
    print("Unable to find file.")
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much. It makes so much more sense to me to learn by seeing why something works instead of why mine didn't. Thank you!!

Comment: @TayenMadsen Post a comment if you need anything clarified, since there are a lot of changes made.

Comment: There are some edge cases that break this code. For example, if someone's name is lodging (could be a last name for example), it might incorrectly increment "lodging" category, even though the record might be a different one. `Lodging;Conference;42342;1231` would be such an example. You should do your comparison against the field with the exact given index.

Comment: @darksky thats actually not true, we drop the name at the beginning and the number at the end of each line when we do `line = line.lower().split(';')[1:-1]`

Comment: Right. But what about `John;Conference;Dinner;21`? It is still looking for any old random string in an array, and it could happen at any index.

Comment: The input looks extremely tight. If OP thinks it could be an issue he can modify it to check the field

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
serviceAmount = ';'.join(s.split(';')[1:-1]) #Removes date and name regardless of format
serviceAmount.split(";")
```

You should do:

```
serviceAmount = ';'.join(s.lower().split(';')[1:-1])
```

You are checking against lower case strings, but not actually lower casing your input.

It is also important to note that `s.lower()` doesn't actually *change* `s`, it just returns a string where all the letters of `s` have been switched to lower case. Same thing for `split` (as in not changing the string its called on, not that it returns a string).

Another problem you are going to run into is getting the numbers from your strings.

```
int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
```

Won't work. You can use `split` again like you did earlier (or just not re-`join` since you only care about the first element in the comparisons).

```
int(serviceAmount.split(';')[1])
```

The last thing is the

```
finally:
    done = True
    inFile.close()
```

`finally` always runs when exiting a try, meaning that you are always done after each loop (and close the file after you read the first line).

If you remove the `finally` and add `inFile.close()` inside the `elif line == ""` it will close, and set `done` only when you've reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as simple as

```
categories = {}

filename = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(filename, "r") as file:

    name, category, value, date = file.readline().split(";")

    if category not in categories:
        categories[category] = {"count": 0, "value": 0}

    categories[category]["count"] += 1
    categories[category]["value"] += int(value)
```

At the end, you'll have a dict with categories, their count, and value, and also their names are not hard-coded.

Comment: This actually does not do the same thing. You need to track `notsure` sum. If you add that you should be good. I'd also wrap that `with` in a `try: except:` since the user manually enters the filename

Comment: There's a lot that can go wrong with above, so religious try-excepting should be left to OP to do.